# Column that are combinations of other columns on JPA's entity

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

My example is,

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyEntity {

private String A;
private String B;
@JsonIgnore @Column(unique = true)
private String C;

    public String getC() {
        return this.A + "_" + this.B;
    }

    public void setC(String C) {
        this.C = this.A + "_" + this.B;
    }
}
```

i want to combine at `C` by `A + B` strings.
because it's my unique key for something useful.
(ps, 
In fact, I should be the only A + B combination. If you have any other suggestion, I would like to recommend it.)

my `POST` request example is,

```
"A" : "value A",
"B" : "value B"
```

without C like above.

so i tried change at getter and setter to `return A+B;`
but it didn't work.(**C is null**)

what should i do???

Comment: Please share your setter/ getter code. In what scenario does it fail?

Comment: Why? Define a unique constraint on the combination of A + B... Then just calculate C in your code, don't make it a column.

Comment: I agree with M. Deinum. But just so you understand what's happening here: if C must  always be equal to A + B, then you shouldn't have any setC() method. setA() and setB() (and all the other methods changing A or B) should be the setters that make sure C is always equal to A + B

Comment: @M.Deinum There is already another primary key in the actual source. Is it possible?

Comment: Where did I mention a primary key? A unique constraint isn't a primary key (although a primary key is by definition unique!).

Comment: Again, use a unique constraint ( a unique constraint isn't limited to a single column!!!)... I strongly suggest you readup on what a database can do for you... It is more then just a dumb container for data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @M.Deinum I solved it by using

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints=@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"A", "B"}))
```